# Bitnami certificate for AWS Mastodon

Tags: amazon-web-services, lets-encrypt, bitnami, mastodon

I'm trying to set up a Mastodon server on AWS instance. Apparently bitnami needs to generate a certificate. Using the bncert-tool, I get a "timed out" error, saying likely a firewall issue.

Using these instructions:
https://oqtacore.com/blog/10-steps-to-create-a-free-mastodon-server/

sudo /opt/bitnami/configure_app_domain --domain yourdoma.in
This resolved the domain names and the IP address fine.

sudo /opt/bitnami/bncert-tool --domains yourdoma.in
Timed out. I expected to get a valid certificate.

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED
I just needed to add the rules to the security group for the instance to access http and https. Then bitnami generated a certificate just fine.
(Always simple after the fact.)